# Using Map to approximate match

Tags: python

```
mapping = {1.0001: 0.0009,
 1.0005: 0.0015,
 1.000666667: 0.0023,
 1.0008: 0.0032,
 1.001: 0.004,
 2.01: 0.0048,
 2.38001428571: 0.0056}


import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({1.03,2.0,2.4}, columns=['Price'])
```

say we wanted to add a new col called 'Margin' and wanted to approximate map the values in the dict to the prices in the price column. how could I get this done?

ie df1['Margin'] = df1['Price'].map(mapping) will work on full matches not approximate

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: a pandas dataframe that has two columns Price and Margin where the prices are as above and the margin figures have been approximated by the dict. Ie 2.0 isnt present in the dict but 2.01 is so we would want that value to be 0.0048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use numpy to make this easy:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create DataFrame as example
df1 = pd.DataFrame({1.03,2.0,2.4}, columns=['Price'])

# Get the mapping values from a dictionary
mapping = {1.0001: 0.0009,
 1.0005: 0.0015,
 1.000666667: 0.0023,
 1.0008: 0.0032,
 1.001: 0.004,
 2.01: 0.0048,
 2.38001428571: 0.0056}

# Convert mapping to two numpy array. The keys are used to find the closest key. 
keys = np.array(list(mapping.keys()))
values = np.array(list(mapping.values()))
# or in one line: 
keys, values = np.array(list(zip(*mapping.items())))

# one value as example how the function works:
# calculate the absolute difference between all keys and the value
# Get the position of the minimum value (argmin)
# based on argmin it is known which key is closest, use that index to get the margin from the values array (values from the mapping dict)
values[np.argmin(np.abs(keys - 1.03))]

# create lambda function so pandas can apply the function on all rows.
get_margin = lambda x: values[np.argmin(np.abs(keys - x))]
# apply the function
df1['margin'] = df1['Price'].apply(get_margin)

df1
   Price  margin
0   1.03  0.0040
1   2.00  0.0048
2   2.40  0.0056


# If you do not want to declare the keys and values array: (I do not see why not but just to show another solution):
get_margin = lambda x: list(mapping.values())[np.argmin(np.abs(np.array(list(mapping.keys())) - x))]
# apply the function
df1['margin'] = df1['Price'].apply(get_margin)
```

Comment: What a brilliant answer @3DspatialUser. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way:

```py
df_res = pd.DataFrame([ [df1.Price.loc[ abs(df1.Price - x).argmin() ], y]\
                       for x, y in mapping.items()], columns=['Margin', 'Price'])
```

Yielding:

```py
#> df_res
   Margin  Price
0   1.03  0.0009
1   1.03  0.0015
2   1.03  0.0023
3   1.03  0.0032
4   1.03  0.0040
5   2.00  0.0048
6   2.40  0.0056
```

In short, you check for the element in df1.Price with smallest absolute difference with each key in `mapping`, then construct a new dataframe to avoid the limitation of repeated index in `dict` structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a linear interpolation, here's a way to do it.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {1.0001: 0.0009,
 1.0005: 0.0015,
 1.000666667: 0.0023,
 1.0008: 0.0032,
 1.001: 0.004,
 2.01: 0.0048,
 2.38001428571: 0.0056}
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame({1.03,2.0,2.4}, columns=['Price'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns = ['Price','Margin'])

print(df1)

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer').set_index('Price').sort_index().interpolate()
print(df3)
print(df3.loc[df1['Price']])
```

Output:

```
         Margin
Price          
1.03   0.004267
2.00   0.004533
2.40   0.005600
```

You could use other interpolation methods (e.g. 'polynomial') from the interpolate method, but many of these will ignore the "outside" values of price such as 2.40, which is larger than all prices with known margins.

Comment: You can also use `df2 = pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns = ['Price','Margin'])`.

Comment: @3DspatialUser Good point, thanks for the tip